# External Link / Leaving Website Link

Tags: hyperlinks

I did a search and came across a similar question which didn't answer my question/angle.

In my web app I am creating I have a number of links that go off my app to a third party. In the post I read it mentioned use box arrow icon.....what are your thoughts about using that and have a splash/in between page notifying the user they are leaving the app?

Thoughts/opinions appreciated

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback really helpful...plenty of food for thought.....I'll creat a quick prototype and get some feedback from users.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? For now this question is a bit too broad to answer with facts. What use do those third party links have for users, where are they placed, who will be clicking them and more important when will they click them?

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to use a box arrow icon for external links if you are opening the link in the same tab (which some organizations do for accessibility reasons.) This prepares the user for a different experience, and helps lessen disorientation and confusion.

Interstitial ("you're now leaving this site") pages are not as commonly used. Yelp uses both a box arrow icon and interstitial pages -- its users are likely in a moment of making fast decisions via multiple pages ("where should I eat now?") and might otherwise accidentally overlook leaving the site. If you think your users are in the same situation and need to be slowed down for understanding, that could be a case for using interstitials. Otherwise, they might annoy users and get in the way of deliberate tasks.

Answer (score 0):

An "Opens in a new window" icon such as [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/5dCy8ruQ6gtCvLF79) one is quite the standard practice.

Given you have a number of links and depending on how many of those links your users are likely to want to visit, adding a `target="_blank"` in order to open in a new window and keep the focus on the current one could be nice.

I'm not a huge fan of in-between pages, seems disruptive for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are correct from my point of view, but missing one major use case for "between page". It is used mainly (and should be used) where users can input their own data/links etc. that are visible to others. The reason is to warn users they are leaving so there is no security risk.
Take Steam for example. Users can add links to their reviews and those links can lead to external web that can be designed as steam site. Without warning, users might think they are still on steam and input passwords, names, cc, etc. The inconvenience coming with extra step is overcame by security.

So to sum it up - It's standard practice to have different link in and out of your app/site (icon/different style); you should use inter step only if it can be security risk or you absolutely have to let the user know he's leaving.